# What's the best PHP array function to use when intersecting nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, intersect

PHP's array is very flexible and useful. I counted over 30 array functions [on the PHP.net array reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) page. Some of them can solve my problem, but I'm looking for the best, most elegant way.

I have 2 arrays, called `labor` and `cost`, each containing a table:

```
labor = array(
   0 => array('date' => date, 'labor'=> labor), 
   1 => array('date' => date, 'labor'=> labor),
   ...
);

cost = array(
   0 => array('date' => date, 'cost'=> cost), 
   1 => array('date' => date, 'cost'=> cost),
   ...
);
```

My problem is that sometimes the number of dates don't match (i.e., there are days when you've incurred costs, even though you spent nothing on labor, or days when you had labor but no cost) - that means there are more lines in one array then the next - no way to know which has without using `count()`.

What I'm interested in are **only the days that had both labor and cost** and I want to end up with an array:

```
laborcost = array(
   0 => array('date' => date, 'labor'=> labor, 'cost' => cost), 
   1 => array('date' => date, 'labor'=> labor, 'cost' => cost),
   ...
)
```

I thought about using `array_intersect()` or one of the 'u' functions, but ended totally mixed up. Before giving up and writing my own array scanning function, I wanted to see if there are any ideas that will solve my issue with 1, possibly 2, lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, `array_map`. I'd create a class, supply one array to the constructor, store it, then use another method in the class as the callback for `array_map` - to which the second array can be supplied.

Comment: Haven't looked at array_map yet - would give it a look. Thanks!

Comment: re: array_map - the user function only accepts one parameter - the array element. If I want to compare it to keys from another array, it cannot be easily done. How do you introduce data into the user function (without using globals)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's is no intersect function accepting a user-defined comparison function that allows you to modify the arrays. The simplest way is just to do it yourself.

Here are a few examples:

**O(2n + m)**

```
// Remap dates as keys for faster lookups
$result = $nlabor = $ncost = array();
foreach ($labor as $l) $nlabor[$l['date']] = $l;
foreach ($cost as $c) $ncost[$c['date']] = $c;

// Compare
foreach ($nlabor as $date => $l) {
    if (array_key_exists($date, $ncost)) {
        $result[] = array_merge($l, $ncost[$date]);
    }
}
```

**~O(n * m)**

```
// Just compare them all
$result = array();
foreach ($labor as $l) {
    foreach ($cost as $c) {
        if ($l['date'] == $c['date']) {
            $result[] = array_merge($l, $c);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which way is the best depends on how many elements you have in each array. When used on smaller arrays *~O(n * m)* is fine, while on bigger arrays *O(2n + m)* will be more efficient.

Comment: Well, this doesn't really address my wanting to use the PHP built in array_ functions, but you deserve the answer for the calculations :)

Comment: There is no built-in function to do what you want to do. All `array_u*` functions do not allow you to modify the arrays, and `array_map` and `array_walk` will basically do the same thing as above, but in a more complex fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This should do that trick. Not quite as simple as a single function.

```
$merge = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($labor); $i++) {
    array_push($merge, array_merge($labor[$i],$cost[$i]));
}
```

Comment: Does not help - what if cost is longer than labor? What if the dates don't match? I only need matching dates - not just a merged array.